# MapBox get div element of Marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Apologies for cross-posting - I have also asked this on StackOverflow...

I am initially pushing MapBox Marker objects to an array via:

```
var el = document.createElement('div' + index);
el.className = 'marker';
deviceMarkers.push(new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [-50 / 2, -50 / 2] }).setLngLat([device.lat, device.lon]).addTo(map));
```

Elsewhere in the code, I extract the marker via:

```
var deviceMarker = deviceMarkers[index];
```

I would like to be able to get 'el' from deviceMarker object, in order to alter the icon size, orientation etc. dynamically. How can I extract 'el' as the original div?

Comment: Could you post a link to the question on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the `mapboxgl.Marker` object so you can latter access this via the `getElement` method, eg:

`deviceMarker.getElement()`

See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker#getelement